# inline tcolorbox with rotated title

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm desperately searching for a way to recreate those really nice **inline-tcboxes** they used in `tcolorbox manual` for, as an example, emphasizing libraries' names.

[image]

I found some topics about left-sided + rotated titles but I can't find a way to adapt the aswers to this specific goal.

Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Copied from `tcolorbox`'s documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtcbox{\mylib}{enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,boxrule=0.4pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  right=0mm,left=4mm,arc=1pt,boxsep=2pt,before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=green!50!black,coltext=green!25!black,colback=green!10!white,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[green!75!blue!50!white] (frame.south west)
    rectangle node[text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,rotate=90] {LIB} ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}}

\MakeRobust\mylib

\ifdefined\pdfstringdefDisableCommands
  \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\mylib#1{'#1'}}
\fi

\begin{document}

Library \mylib{lipsum}:

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

The line `\MakeRobust\mylib` makes `\mylib` robust, so that you can use it in the argument of commands like `\section` or `\caption`.  The line `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` (used only if `hyperref` is loaded) makes `\mylib` produce a sensible PDF outline entry when used in `\section`.  If you then do `\section{Library \mylib{lipsum}}` it won't break (because of `\MakeRobust`), and the PDF outline will say `Library 'lipsum'`.

Comment: I get undefined control sequence in XeTeX when trying this (\pdfstringdefDisableCommands). Also, explaining what is actually happening in the code would help greatly for debugging purposes.

Comment: @OleAldric `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` is from `hyperref`, so I assume you are not loading it, thus the error.  Just remove that line and it should work.  I don't know what each option does (back then I copied from the manual, and these days I know less of `tcolorbox` than I did then :), but other than that the code is straightforward: load packages, define `\newtcbox\mylib`, then `\robustify{\mylib}` makes `\mylib` robust so it doesn't break when used in a `\section` (for example), and the `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` line makes it produce a sensible PDF outline when used in `\section`.

Comment: @OleAldric I added some explanation

Comment: Upvoted, I do have hyperref enabled, but I use this in a class so maybe that causes some havoc. I will research this further. The text in the main box is also ever so slightly offset vertically. Not sure what is going on there, but I guess I need to dive into the documentation for that.

Comment: @OleAldric `lipsum` looks aligned with the baseline of the text to me (but that is done by the `tcolorbox` options, so sorry, I can't help you there). Feel free to ask a question.  Re: `hyperref`: `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` must be after `hyperref` is loaded, so if you're doing it in a class file you may want to do it in `\AtBeginDocument{...}`