# Placing a Colored Text Box within a Sentence

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tcolorbox, box, sentence

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows}

\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=blue,
    colback=blue,
    top=4pt,
    left=5pt,
    right=5pt,
    bottom=4pt,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    %colupper=green!30!black,
    tcbox raise base}
\begin{document}
\Large

% Numbered Box
\logo{\small{\textcolor{white}{1}}}

\vspace{20pt}

In this sentence (1) I would like to replace the previous `(1)' in this sentence by the above blue numbered box. Also, I would like to have the ability to adjust the box's vertical placement in the sentence to accommodate larger boxes. 
\end{document}
```

And the output

[image]

QUESTION: How may I inserted the blue numbered box in a sentence (with the ability to adjust its vertical placement if need be) so that the sentence flows in a natural manner with it?

Note: If there is a more suitable way of producing the colored numbered box for this purpose, please advise so.

Thank you.

Comment: TikZ makes a box like TeX does it for letters, words and so on, so simply write your tikZ code where it shall appear. The other way is to use tcolorbox only.

Comment: @Harald Lichtenstein Thank you for your comment. Would you consider expanding it as a posted answer? Many thanks.

Comment: You can make this task with tcolorbox as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433256/inline-tcolorbox-with-rotated-title

Comment: @cis Thank you for providing this link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost did it! Following code is yours code with an added optional parameter to change whatever option in `\logo` boxes.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\logo}[1][]{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=blue,
    colback=blue,
    top=4pt,
    left=5pt,
    right=5pt,
    bottom=4pt,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    colupper=white,
    %colupper=green!30!black,
    tcbox raise base,
    #1}
\begin{document}
\Large

% Numbered Box
\logo{\small{\textcolor{white}{1}}}

\vspace{20pt}

In this sentence \logo{(1)} I would like to replace the previous 
`(1)' in this sentence by the above blue numbered box. Also, I 
would like to have the \logo[fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries\Huge, 
colupper=orange]{ability} to adjust the box's vertical placement 
in the sentence to accommodate larger boxes. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this suits you?

[image: insert tikz box in text]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\bbox}[2][-2]{\raisebox{#1 pt}{\tikz \node[rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt,fill=blue,text=white]{\footnotesize #2};}}

\begin{document}
    
In this sentence \bbox{1} I would like to replace the previous `(1)' in this sentence by the above blue numbered box. Also, I would like to have the ability to adjust the box's vertical placement in the sentence to accommodate \bbox[-3]{larger boxes}. 

\end{document}
```

Feel free to play with `inner sep` if you want a bolder box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I enlarge the box and make the text bold, the words are no longer aligned with the sentence text. This could be corrected if (1) I could lower the text in the box; or (2) I could vertically adjust the height of the box and its contents. However, with the replacement of my newtcbox{logo}, I have not been able to do either of these things. Would you apprise me of how I may do both of these things? Many thanks.

Comment: The vertical alignment is controled by the first optional argument of the command. In the above code, `larger boxes` is downed by `-3pt` instead of the default `-2pt`.